# Document Template with Picture Placeholder

Tags: 2010, document-template, picture

I'm working on setting up a SharePoint 2010 list to copy new data to a Document Library with a document template.  This allows a new Word document to be automatically created with the template.  (more info on setup [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/brenclarke/archive/2009/04/15/automatically-create-word-documents-which-include-list-fields.aspx))

Everything is working good, except I can't get the template to accept a "Hyperlink or Picture" column content.  More specifically, when I go into my Word template and try to add the column the same way I added the rest of the columns (`Insert`->`Quick Parts`->`Document Property`), the column is not there(Pic1).  To provide some extra info, Pic2 shows the Hyperlink or Picture column type created in this list.  I've Tried Google'ing the subject, but can't find anything.  Also experimented a little bit with no luck.

Is this even possible?  If so, how?

Edit:  I'm open to add-on options also.

Pic1:

[image: Pic 1]

Pic2:

[image]

Comment: It seems others have also had this same problem: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/75116835-9f36-4da1-8159-07a616ede9bd/sharepoint-metadata-and-office-quickparts-hyperlinks-and-pictures-not-appearing-in-the-quick-part?forum=worddev. Perhaps you simply can't add Hyperlink and Picture columns as Quickparts, unfortunately.

Comment: @salomon1996 have you got any solution to your problem. please suggest i am also struck with this picture field is not appearing in document template.

Comment: @ShivendraPatel Unfortunately I do not... Didn't find anything on it.